# Functionnal way of writing huge when rlike statement

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm using regex to identify file type based on extension in DataFrame.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Column, DataFrame}
val ignoreCase        :String = "(?i)"
val ignoreExtension   :String = "(?:\\.[_\\d]+)*(?:|\\.bck|\\.old|\\.orig|\\.bz2|\\.gz|\\.7z|\\.z|\\.zip)*(?:\\.[_\\d]+)*$"
val pictureFileName   :String = "image"
val pictureFileType   :String = ignoreCase + "^.+(?:\\.gif|\\.ico|\\.jpeg|\\.jpg|\\.png|\\.svg|\\.tga|\\.tif|\\.tiff|\\.xmp)" + ignoreExtension
val videoFileName     :String = "video"
val videoFileType     :String = ignoreCase + "^.+(?:\\.mod|\\.mp4|\\.mkv|\\.avi|\\.mpg|\\.mpeg|\\.flv)" + ignoreExtension
val otherFileName     :String = "other"

def pathToExtension(cl: Column): Column = {
    when(cl.rlike( pictureFileType ), pictureFileName ).
    when(cl.rlike( videoFileType ), videoFileName ).
    otherwise(otherFileName)
}

val df = List("file.jpg", "file.avi", "file.jpg", "file3.tIf", "file5.AVI.zip", "file4.mp4","afile" ).toDF("filename")
val df2 = df.withColumn("filetype",  pathToExtension( col( "filename" ) ) )
df2.show
```

This is only a sample and I have 30 regex and type identified, thus the function `pathToExtension()` is really long because I have to put a new `when` statement for each type.
I can't find a proper way to write this code the functional way with a list or map containing the regexp and the name like this :

```
val typelist = List((pictureFileName,pictureFileType),(videoFileName,videoFileType)) 
foreach [need help for this part]
```

All the code I've tried so far won't work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `foldLeft` to traverse your list of `when` conditions and chain them as shown below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

val default = "other"

def chainedWhen(c: Column, rList: List[(String, String)]): Column = rList.tail.
  foldLeft(when(c rlike rList.head._2, rList.head._1))( (acc, t) =>
    acc.when(c rlike t._2, t._1)
  ).otherwise(default)
```

Testing the method:

```
val df = Seq(
  (1, "a.txt"), (2, "b.gif"), (3, "c.zip"), (4, "d.oth")
).toDF("id", "file_name")

val rList = List(("text", ".*\\.txt"), ("gif", ".*\\.gif"), ("zip", ".*\\.zip"))

df.withColumn("file_type", chainedWhen($"file_name", rList)).show
// +---+---------+---------+
// | id|file_name|file_type|
// +---+---------+---------+
// |  1|    a.txt|     text|
// |  2|    b.gif|      gif|
// |  3|    c.zip|      zip|
// |  4|    d.oth|    other|
// +---+---------+---------+
```

Comment: It works thank you, however I have some issue figuring how precisely, I feel like there should be a recursive call inside chainedWhen()

Comment: @Kiwy, not sure I understand your question re: precision.  You could use a recursive function to accomplish the same thing, although there isn't much benefit in this case given that it only needs a linear traversal of a flat list and the `when`s are chained (not nested).  If you go with nesting the `when`s like `when(cond1, x).otherwise(when(cond2, y).otherwise(when...otherwise...))`, a recursive function will be useful.